# Error: multiple definiton of virtual function

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I'm getting an error saying i have multiple definition of void print(). Am i implementing virtual wrongly? Did the same thing for my calculatefees but it seems find. my print function implementation Im just printing something random just to test it.

```
class clsStudent {
    virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

local student class

```
class clsLocalStudent: public clsStudent {    
    virtual void print();
};
```

International Student class

```
class clsInternationalStudent: public clsStudent {
    virtual void print();
};
```

Comment: Please remove all code not relevant to the problem at hand. In this case that'd be all other functions except print. Make sure the problem remains though.

Comment: Multiple definition usually means that you have more than one of the function definitions - since none of the code you have posted so far contain any function definitions, it's hard to say what may be wrong - but perhaps you have made some error such as forgot the `clsInternationalStudent::` in front of `print` when you define the function...

Comment: You've posted a lot of code, but no definition of `print`. I'll hazard a guess that you've defined the function in a header, and included that from more than one source file, so you end up with more than one definition. In that case, either move the definition into a source file, delcare it `inline`, or move it inside the class definition (which makes it implicitly `inline`).

Comment: Please add **your definition for the print methods**, these should be extract from cpp file(s).

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Gosh did not realize that, wasted 1 hr on this. Always looked at the wrong place. Thanks everyone!